# Select the same field based on different foreign keys

Tags: mysql, join, select

I have two tables:

1. Containing a list of products with ids and names
2. A table linking several products with parent-child relationship based on ids using foreign keys.

I want to create a view that will display the product name for both parent and child but both derives from the same table.

1. Each product can be a parent for multiple children
2. Each product can be a child for multiple parents
3. The parenting relationship goes only one level without the need for recursion (no grandchildren)

Here is a sample of the construction of tables:

```
create table plugins_t
(
  rid          int auto_increment,
  product_name varchar(156) not null,
  constraint plugins_t_rid_uindex
    unique (rid)
);

alter table plugins_t
  add primary key (rid);

create table parent_2_childs_t
(
  rid              int auto_increment,
  parent_plugin_id int not null,
  child_plugin_id  int not null,
  constraint parent_2_childs_t_rid_uindex
    unique (rid),
  constraint parent_2_childs_t_plugins_t_rid_fk
    foreign key (parent_plugin_id) references plugins_t (rid),
  constraint parent_2_childs_t_plugins_t_rid_fk_2
    foreign key (child_plugin_id) references plugins_t (rid)
);

alter table parent_2_childs_t
  add primary key (rid);

INSERT INTO plugins_t
  (product_name)
values
  ('product1'),
  ('product2'),
  ('product3'),
  ('product4');

INSERT INTO parent_2_childs_t
  (parent_plugin_id, child_plugin_id)
VALUES
  (1, 3),
  (2, 3),
  (2, 4);

INSERT INTO plugins_t
  (product_name)
values
  ('product1'),
  ('product2'),
  ('product3'),
  ('product4');

INSERT INTO parent_2_childs_t
  (parent_plugin_id, child_plugin_id)
VALUES
  (1, 3),
  (2, 3),
  (2, 4);
```

I used a two select using a subquery but I get duplicate values.

```
select
       pt.product_name as parent_product_name,
       c.product_name as child_product_name
from plugins_t as pt
right join parent_2_childs_t p2ct on pt.rid = p2ct.parent_plugin_id

  join (
    select pt2.product_name from plugins_t as pt2
    join parent_2_childs_t p2ct2 on pt2.rid = p2ct2.child_plugin_id
    ) as c
```

This is the desired output:

```
| Parent name  | child name  |
------------------------------
| product1     | product3    |
| product2     | product3    |
| product2     | product4    |
```

Comment: I guess you're missing a join condition.

Comment: Welcome to dba.se! Bravo on the effort for your first post! Could you add a tag for your dbms (looks like `mysql`, but didn't want to assume)?  As well - given your sample data and desired output, I'm not sure if you mean to ask about recursion or a simple join set for your final output. Could you clarify if you want to enumerate grandchildren, great-grandchildren etc? Or is this just about removing the duplicate values?

Comment: Thank you for your input! I have added the mysql tag (as you guessed).
I edited the question so it will be clear that I'm not looking for recursion looking up grandchildren - only a simple join.
The main problem is that I want to select the same field (product_name) twice - each time based on a different foreign key.

p.s. This is my first time posting here, but I have quite a milage in stackoverflow.
Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query worked

```
  select parent.product_name as parent_product_name, child.product_name as child_product_name
  from plugins_t as parent inner join parent_2_childs_t p2ct on parent.rid = p2ct.parent_plugin_id
  inner join plugins_t as child on child.rid = p2ct.child_plugin_id
```